# Get Angular component's name from the reference

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get a components name in Angular from the reference?

So, having something like this:

```
@Input comp: any;

ngOnInit {
  console.log(this.comp);
}
```

will log the whole component object, but I want only a string with the name of the component.

Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible using `this.constructor.name`.  This will give you the name of the current component.

```
this.constructor.name
```

In your case you can try doing

```
this.comp.constructor.name
```

Comment: actually, ```this.comp.constructor.name``` returns Function, but ```this.comp.name``` returns the name

Comment: Be warned that if you minify your code (which you probably should be doing in production), it'll change the value that this returns (e.g. `MyType` might become `M`). If this is a problem for you, you're better off storing the class name as a static string property.

Comment: Wow, @JoeClay ... i am so happy i stumbled upon your answer. I was pulling my hair out, wondering why my dynamic elements weren't showing in Angular. I was using *ngIf on this.constructor.name... which obviously failed! Thanks!

Comment: @balslev: I was in the exact same situation when i wrote that comment, so I'm glad I could save someone else the stress :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing "comp" Component as a class and want to get the class name of that Component.

```
let compName = this.comp.prototype.constructor.name;
```

Comment: Hi @Keith Hair, could you write out the whole block of code that would get the desired result (i.e., incorporating OP's code) ? I am having trouble following your answer.

Comment: My answer may not be applicable to the OP's usage. I think David is using "comp" as an instance of a Component. Based on Amit's answer, my code is using comp as Class type. `
// 
ngOnInit(){

     this.printComponentName(ArbitraryComponent)

}


printComponentName(comp: any){
    let theCompName = comp.prototype.constructor.name;
    console.log(theCompName);
  }
`